# Power BI - Error Returned: A table of Multiple Values was supplied where a single value was expected

Tags: powerbi, dax

Currently we have a Matrix table with a measure which determines what type of 'Goal' to use (between 'Manual' and 'Automatic') the objective is to return in the 3nd column 'Goal Returned'. Depending on whatever Goal Mode is set on the 2nd column will determine the output of the 'Goal Returned'

For the 'Goal Returned' measure I've written this in DAX:

Decided_LeadInPeriod_New_Leads_Goal = IF(VALUES('Manual Goals - POWER BI DATA'[Goal Mode - New Vehicles])="Manual", [Sum_NewVehiclesManualGoal], Automatic_Goal_Measure[AutomaticGoal_Forecast_New_Leads])

[Result Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UXf1.png)

Strange enough when I just filter for one store it will return me actual results as intended, it follows my if statement perfectly.

[Result when filtering for one store, it works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RavPj.png)

However, if there is more than 1 store in the matrix table, the entire table fails and returns me this error....

[Result returns error when filtering for more than one store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN1HB.png)

Does anyone know how I can implement the intended logic above without it returning an error? Any suggestions on how this can be solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... looks like I needed to use `SELECTEDVALUE` and a `SWITCH` Statement instead of `IF` statement to get this functional!

```
Decided_LeadInPeriod_New_Leads_Goal = SWITCH(
  SELECTEDVALUE('Manual Goals - POWER BI DATA'[Goal Mode - New Vehicles]),
  "Manual",'Manual Goals - POWER BI DATA'[Sum_NewVehiclesManualGoal],
  "Automatic", Automatic_Goal_Measure[AutomaticGoal_Forecast_New_Leads]
)
```

Comment: Correct - in your `IF` predicate, `VALUES` will return a column/table, which is what causes the error, whereas `SELECTEDVALUE` returns a scalar that you can compare to e.g. a string. You could still use `IF` instead of `SWITCH` though. In fact, a `SWITCH` gets translated to a nested `IF` structure in a query.